# Funcion recursiva en c++

Tags: c++, funciones, recursión

Hola me piden: Escriba una función void recursiva que reciba como parámetro solo un entero positivo "n" y que despliegue todos los enteros impares menores a "n".
Estoy aprendiendo recursividad y no me sale del todo, alguien me ayuda??
Esto es lo que tengo:

```
void impares(unsigned int n){
if(n==0){
impares (n);
}else{
if(n%2==0){
impares (n-1);
cout<<n;
}else{
    cout<<n;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Tienes un bucle infinito **muy obvio** en `if (n==0) impares(n);`, te recomiendo revisar el código con calma y una hojita de papel para ir anotando los valores de las cosas en cada iteración.

Comment: @Benito-B Si me parecia que algo andaba mal ahi, pero como plantearia el caso base? Osea si N llega a 0, como hago para parar la funcion??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primero hay un error al manejar el caso base de la recursividad, pues cuando n sea 0, vas a llamar a la misma función usando como parámetro `n=0`, lo que hace que nuevamente vuelvas a llamar a la función usando como parámetro `n=0`, .... y así infinitamente.
El caso base debería terminar la recursividad cuando n == 0:

```cpp
if (n == 0) return;
```

Adicionalmente, la condición para imprimir la respuesta sería **solamente** si n es impar, o sea, si `n % 2 == 1` (n deja resto 1 cuando se divide por 2):

```cpp
if (n % 2 == 1) cout << n << endl;
```

Además siempre se debe llamar a la recursividad, así que tiene sentido hacerlo fuera de todos los `if`.
La función quedaría entonces así:

```cpp
void impares(unsigned int n) {
  if(n == 0) return;
  if(n % 2 == 1) cout << n << endl;
  impares(n-1);
}
```

Espero ayude.

PD: Para que los números sean impresos de menor a mayor, solo hay que cambiar el orden de las lineas 3 y 4:

```cpp
void impares(unsigned int n) {
  if(n == 0) return;
  impares(n-1);
  if(n % 2 == 1) cout << n << endl;
}
```

Comment: Wow era tan simple como eso!! Muchas gracias! La verdad cuesta aprender a pensar recursivamente.

Answer (score 1):

Para detectar los impares debes evaluar que el módulo 2 da 1 (o es distinto de 0, como más te guste).

Así, si quieres que la secuencia sea en orden creciente:

```
void impares(unsigned int n){
  if(n > 0)
  {
      impares(--n);
      if(n % 2 == 1){
          cout << n << '\n';
      }
   }
}
```

Para mostrarla en orden decreciente simplemente debes hacer la llamada recursiva después del `if`

```
void impares(unsigned int n){
  if(n > 0)
  {
      if(n % 2 == 1){
          cout << n << '\n';
      }
      impares(--n);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema era que estás haciendo una comparación incorrecta (para ver los números impares).

```
if(n%2==0)
```

También, aquí estas diciendo que si `n == 0` vas a llamar a la misma función, por la cual esto sucedería infinitas veces.

```
if(n==0){
  impares (n);
}
```

Tu código resultaría así:

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

void impares(unsigned int n){
  if(n==0) {
    return;
  }else {
    if(n%2==1) {
      cout<<n<<endl;
    }
    impares(n-1);
  }
}

int main() {
    impares(30);
}
```

Comment: No hace falta borrar la respuesta y hacer otra. Es preferible editar la respuesta. Los votos negativos se pueden cambiar cuando la respuesta deja de tener errores

Answer (score 0):

```
 int  Sumatorial_impares(int n)
    {
        if (n == 1)
            return 1;
        else
            if (n % 2 == 0)
                return Sumatorial_impares(n - 1);
            else
                if (n % 2 == 1)
                    return (n + Sumatorial_impares(n - 2));
    
    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
    int N;
    cout <<" Ingrese el numero";
    cin>> N;
    cout <<"La sumatoria de los numeros impares es: " <<Sumatorial_impares(N);    
    }
```

Comment: Este ejercicio me lo pidió mi profesor, lo solucioné y lo comparto con ustedes

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. _No compartas código porque sí_. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
/***************************************************
*PRINCIPIO DE INDUCCION
* P(0).
* P(n-1)
********/
using namespace std;

 public void mostrarImparesMenores(int numero)

{
    static int  original = numero;

    if( numero == 1 )     //caso base
    {

         cout<<numero<<endl;

    } else
    {

        mostrarImparesMenores(numero-1);

        if((numero%2 )==1 && numero != original)
        {
            cout<<numero<<endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{

    mostrarImparesMenores(5);

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```